# Unable to render panel in Chrome. Works well in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, extjs, panel

I am trying to render a panel in extJS 3.4.0. It works well in Firefox but gives the following error when I try it in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'applyStyles' of null
>   Ext.Panel.Ext.extend.createElementext-all-debug.js:17057
>   Ext.Panel.Ext.extend.onRenderext-all-debug.js:17127
>   Ext.FormPanel.Ext.extend.onRenderext-all-debug.js:43353
>   Ext.extend.renderext-all-debug.js:10763
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.renderItemext-all-debug.js:13191
>   Ext.layout.AccordionLayout.Ext.extend.renderItemext-all-debug.js:14823
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.renderAllext-all-debug.js:13182
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.onLayoutext-all-debug.js:13168
>   Ext.layout.FitLayout.Ext.extend.onLayoutext-all-debug.js:13383
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.layoutext-all-debug.js:13162
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.runLayoutext-all-debug.js:13271
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.onResizeext-all-debug.js:13265
>   EXTUTIL.Event.fireext-all-debug.js:310
>   EXTUTIL.Observable.fireEventext-all-debug.js:54
>   Ext.Panel.Ext.extend.onBodyResizeext-all-debug.js:17670
>   Ext.Panel.Ext.extend.onResizeext-all-debug.js:17661
>   Ext.BoxComponent.Ext.extend.setSizeext-all-debug.js:12164
>   Ext.layout.FitLayout.Ext.extend.setItemSizeext-all-debug.js:13392
>   Ext.layout.FitLayout.Ext.extend.onLayoutext-all-debug.js:13385
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.layoutext-all-debug.js:13162
>   Ext.layout.CardLayout.Ext.extend.setActiveItemext-all-debug.js:13440
>   Ext.Container.Ext.extend.afterRenderext-all-debug.js:12738
>   Ext.Panel.Ext.extend.afterRenderext-all-debug.js:17414
>   Ext.extend.renderext-all-debug.js:10802
>   Ext.layout.BorderLayout.Ext.extend.onLayoutext-all-debug.js:13768
>   Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.Ext.extend.layoutext-all-debug.js:13162
>   Ext.Container.Ext.extend.doLayoutext-all-debug.js:12969
>   Ext.Container.Ext.extend.afterRenderext-all-debug.js:12743
>   Ext.extend.renderext-all-debug.js:10802
>   Ext.Componentext-all-debug.js:10641
>   Ext.apply.extend.sbext-base-debug.js:246
>   Ext.apply.extend.sbext-base-debug.js:246
>   Ext.apply.extend.sbext-base-debug.js:246 (anonymous
>   function)Ydee.js:27 EXTUTIL.Event.nameext-all-debug.js:190
>   callext-all-debug.js:1459

The code that I have used is:

```
var userDlg = new myDialog();

    var contentPanel = {
        id: 'content-panel',
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'card',
        margins: '2 5 5 0',
        activeItem: 0,
        border: false,
        items: userDlg
    };


    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        title: 'Ext Layout Browser',
        items: [contentPanel],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Can anyone point out the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `Ext.Ready` handler ?

Comment: Yes, the complete code is in `Ext.onReady`

Comment: This kind of error is much easier to explore, if you post a simple working example :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I figured out the problem. Actually I was rendering `FormPanel` inside `Viewport` instead of `Panel`. that's why chrome was giving me such an error. But I don't know why in FF it was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because I was rendering FormPanel inside Viewport instead of Panel.

Accordion layout wasn't functioning in FormPanel. When I changed it to Panel, it started working.

I am not sure why firefox wasn't complaining though.

Comment: I had a similar issue, when generated form elements dynamically. So when inner `form` was generated - issue in Chrome was duplicated (but not in FF). After I've changed to the `panel` - worked well.